# How to return a repository back to the state it was in three commits ago?

Tags: git, undo, git-reset

Consider this Git repository:

```
$ git log -4

commit d7a65d3243259300ff133a28e952fd967df8ff24
Merge: 5572899 65d0d65
Date:   Sun Jul 20 08:23:09 2014 -0400

    Merge branch 'master' of ssh://foo/bar

commit 5572899e00f24f1d6ebc4435ef167508be2dbb47
Date:   Sun Jul 20 07:55:48 2014 -0400

    Commit changes done on server

commit 65d0d65b50a28388ff9073dd6973ee5d115fa141
Date:   Sun Jul 20 14:31:01 2014 +0300

    conflict 21

commit a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428
Date:   Sun Jul 20 13:12:39 2014 +0300

    Update spam filter
```

I need to return the code of the repository to the state that it was in at commit `a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428`. The repository is shared among other developers, all have pulled. **What is the proper way to return the repo to the state of the desired commit?**

Simply doing `git reset --hard a3c629` will not work as I cannot then push the repo:

```
$ git push
To ssh://foo/bar.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://foo/bar.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't want to rebase as there are other developers. **What else can I do?**

Comment: You can reset. Git is warning you to update a ref to an older or different commit because other _might_ have based newer commits on it. But sometimes it's necessary to force-push a branch. Then you should communicate that to your peers. They then perhaps need to rebase their commits onto the new HEAD. Force-push can be done just by preceeding the branch name with a plus sign: `git push <ORIGIN> +<BRANCH NAME>`. Peer developers then need to e.g. `git rebase --onto <ORGIN NAME>/<BRANCH NAME> HEAD~<NUMBER OF COMMITS THEY ADDED>`

Comment: git revert is the proper way

Comment: I highly recommend that you see the [top voted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/456814), it offers additional solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a "forced" revert, meaning creating a new commit, except that new commit would reflect `a3c6295d`, instead of trying to cancel the subsequent commits:

```
# move HEAD, reset index
git reset a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428

# force the files to be like the index
git checkout -- .

# move HEAD back to its previous place
git reset --soft @{1}

# commit the current index (which should reflect a3c6295d)
git commit -m "restore a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428"

git push
```

That way, no need to force the push.

---

The question "[Revert to a previous Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/6309)" proposes a simpler solution, without having to move HEAD from your most recent commit:

```
# restore directly the right commit
git checkout a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428 -- .

# commit the current index (which should reflect a3c6295d)
git commit -m "restore a3c6295de542ae510623921b188be1ef5bb25428"
```

Both solutions do the same: create a *new* commit on top of HEAD, which is useful considering HEAD was already pushed to a remote repo and its history shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Thank you! The comments detailing each step is very helpful.

Comment: For your second set of commands, I think you might actually need to run `git rm -r -- .` first before the checkout, otherwise you'll end up keeping any files that were added after the commit that you're trying to revert back to.